# How to use generic parameter type for another generic class?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

For me it looks like a compiler bug or some strange behavior.
Compiler can't determine generic parameter type in generic class

Code

```
public interface IHamster
{
    int Some { get; set; }
}

public abstract class BaseHamster : IHamster
{
    public int Some { get; set; }
}

public class DerivedHamster : BaseHamster
{
}

class ApplyHitHamster<T> where T : IHamster   // <-- same constraint 
{
    void Zu()
    {
        BaseHamster hamster = null;
        var derived = new DerivedHamster();
        IHamster i = derived;

        var s = new TakeDamageHamster<T>(i); // <<<< Compilation Error on any variables(hamster,derived,i) WHY?????????
        var s2 = new TakeDamageHamster<IHamster>(i); // <<<< But THIS works well
    }
}

class TakeDamageHamster<T> where T : IHamster   // <-- same constraint 
{
    public TakeDamageHamster(T Hamster)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Hamster.Some);
    }
}
```

How can it be possible to use `<T>` with same `where` constraint instead of the `<IHamster>` direct constraint?

Why can't the compiler determine type, if both classes have the same `where T : IHamster`  constraint?

**EDIT:**
Another simplified example:

```
public class BaseHamster
{
    public int Some { get; set; }
}

public class DerivedHamster : BaseHamster
{
}

class ApplyHitHamster<T> where T : BaseHamster, new()   // <-- same constraint 
{
    void Zu()
    {
        BaseHamster hamster = new BaseHamster();
        var derived = new DerivedHamster();

        var s = new TakeDamageHamster<T>();
        s.Method(hamster); // <<<< Compilation Error on any variables(hamster,derived) WHY?????????
    }
}

class TakeDamageHamster<T> where T : BaseHamster, new()  // <-- same constraint 
{
    public void Method(T hamster)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(hamster.Some);
    }
}
```

**Another example:**

```
public class BaseHamster
{
    public int Some { get; set; }
}

class ApplyHitHamster<T> where T : BaseHamster, new()   // MSDN: 
{
    void Zu()
    {
        var hamster = new BaseHamster();
        SuperMethod(hamster);  // <<<< WTF? T is ALWAYS BaseHamster!!!
        SuperMethod(hamster as T);    
    }
    void SuperMethod(T x)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Coming from a Java background, this happens because you're performing an unchecked operation. Usually these are warnings that can be suppressed. This happens because the compiler can't predict the type.

Comment: `TakeDamageHamster` requires an instance of `T` on construction but you are providing an instance of `IHamster` so this correctly fails to compile. You need to provide an instance of `T` either as a parameter to `Zu` or by adding a `new()` constraint to `T` in `ApplyHitHamster`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**How to make it work?**

**1.** What you *can* do to make it work is to cast it to `T`.

```
BaseHamster hamster = null;
var derived = new DerivedHamster();
T i = derived as T;
var s = new TakeDamageHamster<T>(i);
```

But then you also need to add the `class` constraint.

```
class ApplyHitHamster<T> where T : class, IHamster
{
    // Other stuff..
}
```

**2.** Alternatively you can change the constructor to use the interface instead. That will also work.

```
class TakeDamageHamster<T> where T : IHamster
{
    public TakeDamageHamster(IHamster Hamster)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Hamster.Some);
    }
}
```

**3.** Or you can use `new T()`. Remember that this also requires you to add the `new()` constraint.

```
BaseHamster hamster = null;
var derived = new T();

var s = new TakeDamageHamster<T>(derived); // <<<< Compilation Error on any variables(hamster,derived,i) WHY?????????
var s2 = new TakeDamageHamster<IHamster>(derived); // <<<< But THIS works well
```

**Why it doesn't work?**

Because the constraint does not guarantee that `i` is actually derived from `T`. Let's say we create a `AnotherHamster`. Note that it inherits from `BaseHamster`, but not from `DerivedHamster`.

```
public class DerivedHamster : BaseHamster
{
}

public class AnotherHamster : BaseHamster
{
}
```

And now we create an instance of `ApplyHitHamster`.

```
var fooHamster = new ApplyHitHamster<AnotherHamster>();
fooHamster.Zu(); // Let's pretend that the method is public. :)
```

This will in the end try to create an instance of `TakeDamageHamster<AnotherHamster>`. But wait, you're trying to send a `DerivedHamster` to it's constructor.

```
BaseHamster hamster = null;
var derived = new DerivedHamster();
IHamster i = derived;
// You cannot send DerivedHamster when it expects AnotherHamster.
var s = new TakeDamageHamster<T>(i); // T is now AnotherHamster.
```

Remember that `i` is a `DerivedHamster`, but `TakeDamageHamster<AnotherHamster>` expects a `AnotherHamster`. Therefore it does not compile.

**Another example.** Let's say that you initialize your class like so:

```
var fooHamster = new ApplyHitHamster<BaseHamster>();
fooHamster.Zu();
```

Now `T` is `BaseHamster`. Which would make the code look something like this:

```
var derived = new DerivedHamster();
IHamster i = derived;
var s = new TakeDamageHamster<BaseHamster>(i); // Cannot pass IHamster when ctor expects BaseHamster.
```

It will not compile because `TakeDamageHamster` expects a `BaseHamster` (or something that derives from it) as a parameter for it's constructor. But you're sending it a `IHamster`. They are not the same things, even though `BaseHamster` implements `IHamster`. `IHamster` does not derive from `BaseHamster`.

There *might* be several other implementations of `IHamster`, which  does *not* derive from `BaseHamster`. And your code shouldn't break just because another implementation of `IHamster` is created, *right*? So the compiler does not allow that, simply because your constaint does not limit this.

Comment: I don't use AnotherHamster i use <T> where <T> is Base class. And using Special constructor is not what i want

Comment: Yes. I'm just telling you why it won't compile. It will not compile because `T` is not always derived from `DerivedHamster`. Both will be derived from `IHamster`, but that's not what you're using as parameter for the contstructor. in `TakeDamageHamster`.

Comment: T is always derived from Base class because of where constraint. It guarantee that <T> is always BaseClass. Looks like compilator fails to compile because he dont understand same constraints on different classes, i dont have another explanation of that.

Comment: @kalashn1k0v - Yes, but you're not sending `T` to the constructor of `TakeDamageHamster`. You're sending a `DerivedHamster`. And `DerivedHamster` is not necessarily derived from `T`. In your example it will be since you got not other implementations of `BaseHamster`. But the compiler doesn't know that. And it shouldn't break just because you add another implementation.

Comment: I pass <T> to method/constructor, with where contraints, compiler HAS all information about DerivedClass and constraints. So why it is OK to write `TakeDamageHamster<BaseHamster>` but not `TakeDamageHamster<T>` where T is ALWAYS BaseHamster, Looks like This is deffect in compilation process

Comment: @kalashn1k0v - `T` is not guarenteed to be `BaseHamster` because the client chooses `T` and can also add their own implementations of `IHamster`. If you only intend there to be multiple possible parameter types `T` then you don't need generics at all.

Comment: MSDN: where T : <base class name>
The type argument must be or derive from the specified base class.  [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx)  So Compiler ALWAYS guarantee that T is BaseHamster

Comment: @kalashn1k0v - `where T : BaseHamster` ensures that `T` is a subtype of `BaseHamster` but it does _not_ ensure that `BaseHamster` is a subtype of `T` which is  what you require to do `s.Method(new BaseHamster())`.

Answer (score 0):

When Passing T you need constructor like this  beacuse your T can only be type of IHamster

```
public TakeDamageHamster(IHamster i)
        {
            // TODO: Complete member initialization
            this.i = i;
        }
```

public interface IHamster
        {
            int Some { get; set; }
        }

```
    public abstract class BaseHamster : IHamster
    {
        public int Some { get; set; }
    }

    public class DerivedHamster : BaseHamster
    {
    }

    class ApplyHitHamster<T> where T : IHamster   // <-- same constraint 
    {
        void Zu()
        {
            BaseHamster hamster = null;
            var derived = new DerivedHamster();
            IHamster i = derived;

            var s = new TakeDamageHamster<T>(i); // <<<< Compilation Error on any variables(hamster,derived,i) WHY?????????
            var s2 = new TakeDamageHamster<IHamster>(i); // <<<< But THIS works well
        }
    }

    class TakeDamageHamster<T> where T : IHamster   // <-- same constraint 
    {
        private IHamster i;

        public TakeDamageHamster(T Hamster)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Hamster.Some);
        }

        public TakeDamageHamster(IHamster i)
        {
            // TODO: Complete member initialization
            this.i = i;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with this line.

```
var s = new TakeDamageHamster<T>(i);
```

The reason why this is throwing an error is because there is no guarantee that T will be of type DerivedHamster. That is, T is guaranteed to be of type IHamster only.  Recommended would be using the following line.

```
var s2 = new TakeDamageHamster<DerivedHamster>(derived);
```

Also consider using a helper method to make the code a bit easier to read.

```
class ApplyHitHamster<T> where T : IHamster  
{
    void Zu()
    {
        var derived = new DerivedHamster();
        var s2 = new TakeDamageHamster<DerivedHamster>(derived); 
        var s3 = CreateTakeDamageHamster(derived);
    }

    TakeDamageHamster<T2> CreateTakeDamageHamster<T2>(T2 hammie)
        where T2 : IHamster 
    {
        return new TakeDamageHamster<T2>(hammie);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It works OK. Imagine you have `ApplyHitHamster<DerivedHamster>`. Now, content of `Zu` unwinds to :

```
IHamster i = derived;

var s = new TakeDamageHamster<DerivedHamster>(i);
```

You can clearly see that ctor of `TakeDamageHamster` requires `DerivedHamster` and you're trying to pass bare `IHamster` to it. It cannot work.

if you want your `Zu` to work as it is, you need to do:

```
class TakeDamageHamster<T> where T : IHamster   // <-- same constraint 
{
    public TakeDamageHamster(IHamster Hamster)//<-- now this is compatible with constraint alone, no matter what T is.
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Hamster.Some);
    }
}
```

Now, you can create `TakeDamageHamster` with any generic parameter you want and initialize it with only base interface.